# Prove the number of words $w$ of length $n$ on the alphabet $[n]$ such that $w_{n−i} > i$ and $w_{i} ≤ w_{i+1} + 1$ is ${\frac 1{n+1}}{2n\choose n}$

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove the number of words $w$ of length $n$ on the alphabet $[n]$ such that $w_{n−i} > i$ and $w_{i} ≤ w_{i+1} + 1$ is ${\frac 1{n+1}}{2n\choose n}$

I am actually stuck on what is being asked.  I thought I could build a relation, but the inequalities are throwing me off.

Comment: @BillO'Haran I tried to manipulate the $w$ terms given into a relation, but I am a complete novice; I am at a standstill.  I tried plugging in small, discrete integers to try to get a better picture, but the inequalities are not making sense to me.

Comment: How have $[n]$ and $w_{i}$ been defined?

Comment: Do you know what the Catalan numbers are? They are given by $\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$, so you're really showing that the number of these words is equal to the Catalan numbers. This could be useful since the Catalan numbers have an interpretation (well, many interpretations, but one that could be particularly useful here) as counting what are called Catalan paths, so you could show a bijection between these words and Catalan paths. Granted, if this is coming from a course/text that hasn't taught you about Catalan numbers, then you shouldn't try to introduce them just for this exercise.